# PHP concat int - result int

Tags: php

I've to append a fixed int to a variable int. $a=variable number.

$b has to be $a+002 (for example). So, for example,

```
$a = 1; $b=1002
$a = 2; $b=2002
$a = 58; $b=58002
```

I could do `$b=$a.'002'`; but this will be a string, right?

I've to put $b into a mySql database in a int(11) column.

Which is the most correct and safe way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: It looks like you are just multiplying $a by 1000. Is there any reason why `$b = $a * 1000;` won't work?

Comment: I don't need help in multiplying by 1000. I put 000 as example, it can be also any other number, e.g. 002.
Adjusted the example.

Comment: Then you just need to concatenate the string '002' onto $a. `$b = $a . '002'`. Correct?

Comment: Yes, but the result has to be a number variable, not a string, so I can put it into a int mysql column. I tried $b=$a.'002' and this works in echo, but like I wrote, I'm worried it's read as a string rather than a number. I'm coming from JAVA so maybe I've confused ideas, sorry if this is a stupid question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you could just concatenate the string '002' onto $a.

`$b = $a . '002'`

The result will be a string, but  it doesn't really matter. MySQL will parse it as an integer when you run your query.

If you really wanted an integer result you could just cast it as such:

`$b = (int) ($a . '002');`

Even if you cast it to an integer, your query is still going to be a string. On MySQL's end the query is going to be the same either way.